# Track user position when app is closed in Phonegap app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

In my Phonegap app, I want to implement a local notification similar to:

[image: this one]

as done by Google Maps.

In other words, the app should detect when the device is near a specific location and ask the user if he wants to check in.

It must NOT be a service running when the app is in the background or killed, but it has to run when the app is completely closed (My background service is working).

I suppose there is no way to get this done by using the traditional Phonegap JS plugins, how can this be achieved otherwise? I suppose it must be some kind of Java daemon running on the device?

And is this kind of tracking even allowed in the Android and iOS TOS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Background Geolocation plugin?

http://devfanaticblog.com/background-geolocation-with-apache-cordova/

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "My background service is working". I need a solution that runs when the user never "started" the app. 
I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/pmwisdom/cordova-background-geolocation-services)

Comment: Just took a depper look at the plugin you provided. Apparently it has functionalities to load on boot and continue running after termination which seems to be pretty useful. With all the different Background Geolocation plugins it's difficult to keep track of all the functionalites...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start your app automatically at every boot time then probably you need to use the following plugin

[[1]: https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-boot-launcher/

The plugin will take care of starting the app every time when phone booted. Then u can call background geolocation to track the user position.